# nanobind incompatible function argument types

Tags: python, c++, nanobind

I have this basic example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <nanobind/nanobind.h>

class T {
public:
    T(std::string s) {
        std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
    };
}

NB_MODULE(basic_example, m) {

    nb::class_<T>(m, "T")
    .def(nb::init<std::string>())
    ;
}
```

When I try to compile, I'm getting the error:

> TypeError: **init**(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:     1. **init**(self, arg: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >, /) -> None

I'm new to nanobind and unfamiliar with how to fix it.

Comment: Can you make this question a bit more complete, with definition of `class T`, and included headers (especially that the answer is that some headers are missing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason (probably performance), just using `#include <nanobind/nanobind.h>` will not give you access to `std::string` interoperability, for that you will need to make sure you include `nanobind/stl/string.h` and recompile it it will work.

Comment: Good answer, in general to bind/convert the STL types (like vector, unordered_map etc) you need to #include the matching header in nanobind. That's different to how boost::python or pybind11 operated.

Comment: It's just so that you can bind functions taking/returning vectors, strings etc. Probably done like this to make the resulting code smaller and have it compile faster, if you do not need certain features.